# silverstripe HtmlEditorField with max length of characters?

Tags: content-management-system, silverstripe

i´m trying to paste a very long htmlText (130000 Characters) to the content field of a silverstripe page. after saving is done the content field remains blank.

I was able to paste the htmlText directly to the Content field in the database. The database does not complain and I can display the text in the frontend.

So it looks like there is a limitation in the HtmlEditorField. Is there a kind of max length of characters for the HtmlEditorField?

greetz,
Florian

Comment: hey! it´s 3.0.5. the funny thing is: I´m taking the long text from an 2.4 installation. there it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like a bug to me. [HTMLText](https://github.com/silverstripe/silverstripe-framework/blob/3.0/model/fieldtypes/HTMLText.php) is limited to 2MB and [HtmlEditorField](https://github.com/silverstripe/silverstripe-framework/blob/3.0/forms/HtmlEditorField.php) shouldn't add any limit to that IMHO. And I couldn't find anything related to it while taking a quick look at the class on the 3.0 branch.